# Have an issue with "will_paginate" and searching posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, will-paginate

I have created a simple search form, using a `form_tag`., and I have a gem `will_paginate`. When I try to search something, an error occcures: `undefined method 'total_pages' for #<Post::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f91ca043130>`

Here is a part of my post_controller.rb:

```
 def index
     @posts = unless params[:search].nil?
       Post.search(params[:search])
     else
       @posts = Post.paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 5)
    end
 end
```

The model post.rb:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  default_scope -> {order('created_at DESC')}
  validates :user, presence: true
  validates_presence_of :title, :body, :tags
  validates :title, length: { in: 5..100}
  validates :tags, uniqueness: true
  validates :user_id, presence: true

  def self.search(search)
    where("title LIKE ? OR body LIKE ?", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%")
  end

end
```

And a view posts_index:

```
<%= form_tag(posts_path, method: 'GET') do%>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], class: 'input-sm',placeholder: 'Search for...'%>
    <%= image_submit_tag('search.png', class: 'picture_size')%>
<% end %>

<%= will_paginate %>

<% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <p> <%= post.title %> </p>
    <p><%= post.body %> </p>
    <p> <%= post.tags %> </p>
<% end %>

<% will_paginate %>
```

It still works fine, unless I try to search for something. Only after searching I recieve an error. How can I solve the issue?

Comment: add `paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 5)` to `Post.search(params[:search])`